# Google Finance stock market functions update time

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I use a Google Finance function to call the SP500 close.

I collected with this method the historical data going back a year. The data fills in daily and for every date the function is called.

The issue is what time it updates.  The market closes at 4PM EST. It's now 5AM EST the next day and the data is not updating. Why?

`=iferror(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE($E$1,"CLOSE",$A5022),2,2),0)`

`E1`: .INX

`A5022`: 20230504

The problem occurs for multiple US stock index symbols (SP500, Nasdaq 100) and ETFS's such as 'RSP' and 'IJR'.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://www.google.com/googlefinance/disclaimer/), `GOOGLEFINANCE` can have a delay of up to 20 minutes. If this is taking longer, you can report this issue through the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) so Google is aware of this behavior and provides a solution.

Comment: Thank you.  I am struggling with creating an 'issue' in the Issue Tracker. Possibly it's the 'Component' I need to choose, and the examples below I don't seem to  match: (https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/concepts/components). But I am not sure.